# Logging the result of filter while using java streams filter by predicate

Tags: java, logging, filter, java-8, java-stream

The scenario is there are different types of filters I have created which filters the list of some objects based on the property of the object.

So for that I have created an AbstractObjectFilter class which inherited by every filter.
AbstractObjectFilter.java

```
public abstract class AbstractEventFilter
{
    protected abstract Predicate<IEvent> isEligible();

    public List<IEvent> getFilteredEvents(final List<IEvent> events)
    {
        return events.stream().filter(isEligible()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

So now every filter extends this class and overrides the isEligible() and in that function it returns the predicate based on its properties.

For eg:- 
MinNumOfPrizesFilter.java

```
public class MinimumNumOfPrizesFilter extends AbstractEventFilter
{
    private int minimumNumOfPrizes;

    public MinimumNumOfPrizesFilter(@NonNull int minimumNumOfPrizes)
    {
        this.minimumNumOfPrizes = minimumNumOfPrizes;
    }

    @Override
    protected Predicate<IEvent> isEligible()
    {
        return event -> event.getPrizeCount() >= minimumNumOfPrizes;
    }
}
```

Similarly there are many other filters I have created. There is one applyFilter function which iterate over the list of filter objects and keep applying filter by call getFilteredEvents function.

Now how can i log the fate of each event For example - "x1 event was filtered by MinNumOfPrizesFilter filter. x1's prize count - 10 , required min prize count - 20"

Comment: What’s the point of the lambda expression here? Compared to the conventional approach of just letting `AbstractEventFilter` implement `Predicate<IEvent>` directly, so that subclasses only have to implement the `test` method, it’s not a simplification.

Comment: By the way, it is pointless to annotate an `int` variable with `@NonNull` as `int` values can never be `null` anyway.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can simply add brackets to your lambda expression and add the logging statement right before the validation :

```
return event -> {
    // LOG.info(event.getName() + " was filtered...") or whatever you use for logging.
    return event.getPrizeCount() >= minimumNumOfPrizes;
}
```

Note that there exists a `peek` operation which is meant to be used mostly for logging on java streams :

```
events.stream()
      .peek(event -> System.out.println("Filtering event" + event.getName()))
      .filter(isEligible())
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but that is not helping here, as you need to log in `AbstractEventFilter`  implementations.

Comment: with this you are logging the filtered and the unfiltered values

Comment: @P.J.Meisch I know that. The peek operation does not suit here, just added it informationally as it is many times helpful for logging using java-streams.

Comment: and you would need to implement it in every derived class

Comment: @P.J.Meisch Given that the predicates may vary in any implementation, and that OP want to print these information (i.e minimumNumOfPrizes), this is needed.

Answer (score 3):

perhaps not the prettiest solution, but it works and you only change your abstract base class:

```
abstract class AbstractEventFilter {

    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getCanonicalName());
    private final String filterName = getClass().getSimpleName();

    protected abstract Predicate<IEvent> isEligible();

    private Predicate<IEvent> internalIsEligible() {
        return iEvent -> {
            boolean res = isEligible().test(iEvent);
            if (!res) {
                logger.info("event " + iEvent.toString() + " filtered by " + filterName);
            }
            return res;
        };
    }

    public List<IEvent> getFilteredEvents(final List<IEvent> events) {
        return events.stream().filter(internalIsEligible()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

you keep your derived classes implementing `isELigible()` as before, only in your `getFilteredEvents` method, you call the `internalIsEligibable` method instead.

Comment: How do you print the minimumNumOfPrizes ?

Comment: Upvote for only logging the ones that get filtered out.